# ERPNext: Join multiple tables using script report

Tags: erpnext, frappe

Anyone know what is the ORM function for joining multiple db tables in ERPNext?
I need query result from 2 DB tables join using script report

*I don't need query report answer since i already have it. I only looking for an example do it using script report

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frappe currently doesn't have ORM support for joining tables. You might have to use `frappe.db.sql` for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

data = frappe.db.sql(
"""
select tb1.name from `tabTable1` as tb1
left join `tabTable2` as tb2 on tb1.name = tb2.employee_name;
"""
);
return data